# WindowsMobile - How to check if there is WIFI connection?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

how I can check if in my Windows mobile program there is WIFI connection ?

(I dont want to use try & catch for any action)

I work with Windows mobile 2005, FW 3.5, WS2008

thank's in advance

Comment: This [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715318/best-way-to-manage-network-state-in-windows-mobile) might help you.

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status namespace has an extensive set of information items. Now WiFi isn't directly mentioned (Bluetooth and cellualr are) but you can check for 'Any' network connection with SystemState.ConnectionsCount and SystemState.ConnectionsDescriptions.

For more precision, check the OpenNetCF library (as usual).